# How to use 2 ports for same VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have an F5 URL portal.example.com which points to an Oracle HTTP Server(OHS) on specific port 85. I have below settings in custom file under moduleconf folder.

```
NameVirtualHost *:85
<VirtualHost *:85>
ServerName portal.example.com:85
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://portal.example.com/webcenter/portal/MyPortal
RewriteRule ^/webcenter/(portal|portal/home)?$ http://portal.example.com/webcenter/portal/MyPortal [R=301,L]

<Location /webcenter>
 SetHandler weblogic-handler
 WebLogicCluster portalmachine01:9001,portalmachine01:9002
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

This setting works fine. When users type portal.example.com on browser, the port 85 is not being displayed as this port is mapped to OHS IP address at F5 level.

Now I want to install Oracle WebCache to improve performance on portal. I want to use same server name and also include webcache port 7788 to same settings. How can I make changes to above virtual host settings so that both ports work on same server name? Please remember that we don't want user to see any port(85 or 7788) in browser. Do we need also need to change port mapping for this server name at F5 level too?

Appreciate your pointers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

WebCache is supposed to run as a reverse proxy in front of OHS.
You should point the BigIp LB to WebCache and then register OHS as an origin server under WebCache and map your virtual host in WebCache to the OHS origin server.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I will ask network team to change the port from OHS to webcache at F5 level.

Comment: Just take care to have webcache configured before they do that. You can test it beforehand by accessing webcache's ip:port directly.

Comment: Yes. webcache is configured and I am able to access webcache admin console too. I also did the mapping for webcache to OHS origin server.

Comment: Then you're set! Let me know if it works.